# Allow user to select specific row of sql select results?

Tags: php, sql

Not sure if this is even possible so sorry if this is a stupid question.  I have a sql select query that I will post below.  It displays 5 fields into a table from my orders database table.  Is there any way that a user can click on one of the rows and then that would take them to a new page showing only that rows results?  Is it somehow possible to store the select query results into a session for me to call on the next page?  I would like them to be able to print invoices this way.  Here is the select sql code.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, login_id, companyname, address, cost FROM orders WHERE   `login_id` = '$_SESSION[login]'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>id</th><th>login_id</th><th>companyname</th>tr><th>address</th><th>cost</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["login_id"]."</td><td>".$row["companyname"]."</td><td>".$row["address"]."</td><td>".$row["cost"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: It looks like PHP to me. Is it?

Comment: The answer to both your questions is "yes"...

Comment: Yes it is PHP @PatrickHofman.

Comment: @Bartdude  any examples of how to do that would be much appreciated.  I am learning fast but still have a lot to understand still!

Comment: Have you tried to look up how Sessions work? It should be fairly simple to figure out just following google results.

Comment: @DarkAshelin  Yes I have learned how sessions works.  I am using a session in the SELECT query to only show table of orders from the logged in user so I understand how that works.  Just gets confusing to me as to how I would have a link or buton next to each row that is displayed that user can click on that will display that specific row on next page.  Even more confusing to me is how I would have this link or button auto generated based from each rows data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on i486's answer, here is how you can achieve it in more detail:

Since you already have the `$row["id"]`, you can use this to generate a link:

```
echo "<a href='newpage.php?id=".$row["id"]."'>Click here</a>";
```

Now in **newpage.php**:

```
// You can access parameters in the url using GET
$id = $_GET["id"];

// Now you can build a new SQL query using this $id, and echo the results table
```

Do look up the following things:

- REST: This explains how GET and POST works
- Prepared SQL statements: This will prevent SQL injection, and is needed when you are working with GET or POST values in an SQL query (otherwhise malicious users can destroy your database!)

Comment: This is perfect.  Thanks for spelling it out for me lol  Thanks again! @DarkAshelin

Answer (score 1):

Simply save the value of first column (ID). Then use it for new query which selects only this row.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Sounds like a great solution but I wouldn't know where to start to make that happen.  Also,  would this method allow for a link or button that is auto generated for the user to click on so I wouldn't have to manually update every single row each time an order comes in? @i486

Comment: @bg2982 Yes, you could for example create an `<a href="">` link with the ID in the url, and then use PHP's `$_GET` to retrieve this ID and use it in an SQL query.